# How to insert selected content of a file into another file after a pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I wanted to extract the IPs under [abc] from file1, and use them to replace the list of hosts in file 2:

File1:

```
[abc]
192.168.29.153
192.168.29.155
[def]
192.168.29.153
[xyz]
192.168.29.153
```

File 2:

```
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["192.168.29.115:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"
```

Comment: what goes where? I don't see any connection between "abc" or "192.168.29.153" or "192.168.29.115" ...

Comment: I want to extract the lines below [abc] : 192.168.29.153
192.168.29.155 and put them in the second file on the list of hosts just like that:  hosts: ["192.168.29.153","192.168.29.155"]

Comment: Why does the .115 host have a port with it? Do they all need that port added?

Comment: yes, but I can add it manually on the file. No problem with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it, if `awk` is ok.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# here, NR is record number, and FNR is *file* record number - this matches only 
# in first file
NR == FNR {
    # if first field matches
    if ($1 ~ /abc/) {
        # arrange addresses with `", "` between them
        abc=$2
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) abc = abc "\", \"" $i
    } 
    # then we're finished with this file.
    next;
}

$1 ~ /hosts/ {
    # print the saved addresses formatted with `["` addr `"]`
    printf "  %s [\"%s\"]\n", $1, abc ;
    next
 }

# print any other lines with no editing.
{ print }
```

Gives output for the updated file as the below. Note that the built in variable RS (record seperator) is being updated between files though, to treat each separately.

```
~$ ./log_edit RS='[' hosts RS='\n' logstash
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
   hosts: ["192.168.29.153", "192.168.29.155"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem
```

You'll also need to save the output then replace the old file.

Comment: oh, I didn't see that there had been a change to the question..

Comment: sorry yes.. because it a list of IPs not only one

Comment: I tried to run the awk command like that : awk script_awk fileabc filehosts
but nothing was changed on the filehosts ... still  `hosts: ["192.168.29.115:5044"]`

Comment: You need to call it like it is in the example, including the RS='...' file1 RS='...' file2. Otherwise it's not using the correct idea of a record. THe first file treats between [ characters like a line, almost.

Comment: Thank you so much ! but is it possible to put the new hosts line on the file logstash instead of the old line ? I mean apply the changes to the file itself and not to just display it on the output. Thx for your help !

Comment: Redirect it to a new file and copy it once this programme has definitely succeeded. You can't do it in place with ask directly. There's questions about how to automate the replacement.

Comment: One last thing please, is it possible to remove the old list of hosts and replace it with the new one with only the hosts parsed from the first file ? I mean overwrite and not add to the existent list

Comment: like the above?

Comment: Yesss !! Thxxxxx